# The Next-gen Databases

Tags: sql, database, nosql, non-relational-database

I'm learning traditional Relational Databases (with [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/)) and doing some research I've come across some new types of databases. [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/), [Drizzle](https://launchpad.net/drizzle), and [Scalaris](http://www.zib.de/CSR/Projects/scalaris/) to name a few, what is going to be the next database technologies to deal with?

Comment: Could someone please update this question to refer to "databases" instead of "SQL"?

Comment: Even though randin is using the term SQL incorrectly, I think that change would be against the spirit of peer editing.

Comment: too late.. sorry Bill.  Feel free to roll back my edit if you feel strongly.  I made my change before you posted your comment.  I think rephrasing it the way I did is both educational to the OP and more useful to the community.

Comment: Well, it's good to be correct.  A tech writer friend of mine said, "you can't get the right answers unless you ask the right questions."

Comment: Ah, sorry about the misleading question, my knowledge of SQL and databases was non-existent when I asked the question.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I would say next-gen *database*, not next-gen SQL.

SQL is a language for querying and manipulating relational databases.  SQL is dictated by an international standard.  While the standard is revised, it seems to always work within the relational database paradigm.

Here are a few new data storage technologies that are getting attention (circa 2008 when I wrote this answer):

- [**CouchDB**](http://couchdb.apache.org/) is a non-relational database.  They call it a document-oriented database.
- [**Amazon SimpleDB**](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/) is also a non-relational database accessed in a distributed manner through a web service. Amazon also has a distributed key-value store called **Dynamo**, which powers some of its S3 services.
- [**Dynomite**](http://github.com/cliffmoon/dynomite/tree/master) and [**Kai**](http://kai.wiki.sourceforge.net/) are open source solutions inspired by Amazon Dynamo.
- [**BigTable**](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html) is a proprietary data storage solution used by Google, and implemented using their Google File System technology.  Google's MapReduce framework uses BigTable.
- [**Hadoop**](http://hadoop.apache.org/core/) is an open-source technology inspired by Google's MapReduce, and serving a similar need, to distribute the work of very large scale data stores.
- [**Scalaris**](http://www.zib.de/CSR/Projects/scalaris/) is a distributed transactional key/value store. Also not relational, and does not use SQL. It's a research project from the Zuse Institute in Berlin, Germany.
- [**RDF**](http://www.w3.org/RDF/) is a standard for storing semantic data, in which data and metadata are interchangeable.  It has its own query language SPARQL, which resembles SQL superficially, but is actually totally different.
- [**Vertica**](http://www.vertica.com/) is a highly scalable column-oriented analytic database designed for distributed (grid) architecture.  It does claim to be relational and SQL-compliant.  It can be used through Amazon's Elastic Compute Cloud.
- [**Greenplum**](https://greenplum.org/) is a high-scale data warehousing DBMS, which implements both MapReduce and SQL.
- [**XML**](http://www.w3.org/XML/) isn't a DBMS at all, it's an interchange format.  But some DBMS products work with data in XML format.
- [**ODBMS**](http://www.odbms.org/), or Object Databases, are for managing complex data.  There don't seem to be any dominant ODBMS products in the mainstream, perhaps because of lack of standardization.  Standard SQL is gradually gaining some OO features (e.g. extensible data types and tables).
- [**Drizzle**](https://launchpad.net/drizzle) is a relational database, drawing a lot of its code from MySQL.  It includes various architectural changes designed to manage data in a scalable "cloud computing" system architecture.  Presumably it will continue to use standard SQL with some MySQL enhancements.
- [**Cassandra**](http://incubator.apache.org/cassandra/) is a highly scalable, eventually consistent, distributed, structured key-value store, developed at Facebook by one of the authors of Amazon Dynamo, and contributed to the Apache project.
- [**Project Voldemort**](http://project-voldemort.com/) is a non-relational, distributed, key-value storage system.  It is used at LinkedIn.com
- [**Berkeley DB**](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/index.html) deserves some mention too.  It's not "next-gen" because it dates back to the early 1990's.  It's a popular key-value store that is easy to embed in a variety of applications.  The technology is currently owned by Oracle Corp.

Also see this nice article by Richard Jones: "[Anti-RDBMS: A list of distributed key-value stores](http://www.metabrew.com/article/anti-rdbms-a-list-of-distributed-key-value-stores/)."  He goes into more detail describing some of these technologies.

Relational databases have weaknesses, to be sure.  People have been arguing that they don't handle all data modeling requirements since the day it was first introduced.

Year after year, researchers come up with new ways of managing data to satisfy special requirements:  either requirements to handle data relationships that don't fit into the relational model, or else requirements of high-scale volume or speed that demand data processing be done on distributed collections of servers, instead of central database servers.

Even though these advanced technologies do great things to solve the specialized problem they were designed for, relational databases are still a good general-purpose solution for most business needs.  SQL isn't going away.

---

I've written an article in php|Architect magazine about the innovation of non-relational databases, and data modeling in relational vs. non-relational databases. http://www.phparch.com/magazine/2010-2/september/

Comment: Hey Bill, we do tend to answer the same questions a lot.. your answer here is thorough enough I don't feel writing my own would be of much use -- want to add some info about Vertica et al, and Greenplum and friends, to make it more complete?

Comment: Thank you Bill for the through answer, I'll just stick with PostgreSQL for the time being.

Comment: PostgreSQL is a fine choice for RDBMS.  Have fun!

Answer (score 25):

I'm missing **graph databases** in the answers so far. A graph or network of objects is common in programming and can be useful in databases as well. It can handle semi-structured and interconnected information in an efficient way. Among the areas where graph databases have gained a lot of interest are semantic web and bioinformatics. RDF was mentioned, and it is in fact a language that represents a graph. Here's some pointers to what's happening in the graph database area:

- [Graphs - a better database abstraction](http://whydoeseverythingsuck.com/2008/03/graphs-better-database-abstraction.html)
- [Graphd, the backend of Freebase](http://blog.freebase.com/2008/04/09/a-brief-tour-of-graphd/)
- [Neo4j open source graph database engine](http://neo4j.org/)
- [AllegroGraph RDFstore](http://agraph.franz.com/)
- [Graphdb abstraction layer for bioinformatics](http://code.google.com/p/pygr/)
- [Graphdb behind Directed Edge recommendation engine](http://blog.directededge.com/2009/02/27/on-building-a-stupidly-fast-graph-database/)

I'm part of the [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) project, which is written in Java but has bindings to Python, Ruby and Scala as well. Some people use it with Clojure or Groovy/Grails. There is also a [GUI tool](http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Neoclipse) evolving.

Comment: How about http://www.db4o.com/, an object-database, but its designed around managing object graphs.

Comment: Object databases (OODB) are different from graph databases. Simply put a graphdb won't tie your data directly to your object model. In a graphdb relationships are first class citizens, while you'd have to implement that on your own in an OODB. In a graphdb you can have different object types represent different views on the same data. Graphdbs typically support things like finding shortest paths and the like.

Answer (score 10):

Might be not the best place to answer with this, but I'd like to share this taxonomy of noSQL world created by Steve Yen (please find it at http://de.slideshare.net/northscale/nosqloakland-200911021)

1. **key‐value‐cache**

   - memcached
   - repcached
   - coherence
   - inﬁnispan
   - eXtreme scale
   - jboss cache
   - velocity
   - terracoqa
2. **key‐value‐store**

   - keyspace
   - ﬂare
   - schema‐free
   - RAMCloud
3. **eventually‐consistent key‐value‐store**

   - dynamo
   - voldemort
   - Dynomite
   - SubRecord
   - MongoDb
   - Dovetaildb
4. **ordered‐key‐value‐store**

   - tokyo tyrant
   - lightcloud
   - NMDB
   - luxio
   - memcachedb
   - actord
5. **data‐structures server**

   - redis
6. **tuple‐store**

   - gigaspaces
   - coord
   - apache river
7. **object database**

   - ZopeDB
   - db4o
   - Shoal
8. **document store**

   - CouchDB
   - Mongo
   - Jackrabbit
   - XML Databases
   - ThruDB
   - CloudKit
   - Perservere
   - Riak Basho
   - Scalaris
9. **wide columnar store**

   - BigTable
   - Hbase
   - Cassandra
   - Hypertable
   - KAI
   - OpenNep

Answer (score 2):

For a look into what academic research is being done in the area of next gen databases take a look at this: http://www.thethirdmanifesto.com/

In regard to the SQL language as a proper implementation of the relational model, I quote from  wikipedia, "SQL, initially pushed as the standard language for relational databases, deviates from the relational model in several places. The current ISO SQL standard doesn't mention the relational model or use relational terms or concepts. However, it is possible to create a database conforming to the relational model using SQL if one does not use certain SQL features."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model (Referenced in the section "SQL and the relational model" on March 28, 2010

Answer (score 1):

Not to be pedantic, but I would like to point out that at least CouchDB isn't SQL-based.  And I would hope that the next-gen SQL would make SQL a lot less... fugly and non-intuitive.

Comment: A friend of mine said, "It's supposed to be hard to read!  It's called *code* for a reason!"  :-)

Comment: My brain is broken, I like SQL, too much looking at it grow on to you :)

Answer (score 1):

There are special databases for XML like MarkLogic and Berkeley XMLDB. They can index xml-docs and one can query them with XQuery. I expect JSON databases, maybe they already exist. Did some googling but couldn't find one.

Comment: There are a few that provide a JSON interface to the data. Terrastore is one example.

Answer (score 0):

SQL has been around since the early 1970s so I don't think that it's going to go away any time soon.

Maybe the 'new(-ish) sql' will oql (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODBMS)

Answer (score 0):

I heard also about NimbusDB by Jim Starkey

Jim Starkey is the man who "create" Interbase

who work on Vulcan (a Firebird fork)

and who was at the begining of Falcon for MySQL