# MySQL select where JSON field property has value

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-5.7

How to write a basic MySQL query that has a WHERE on a property within a JSON data-type field? I don't see basic where clause q for json fields on SO.

Something like this, but of course these dont work:

```
SELECT * from my_table where meta_data->name = 'bob';

SELECT * from my_table where meta_data[name] IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Some examples of how to query a json data type field:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(meta_data, "$.first_name") = 'bob';

SELECT * FROM users
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(meta_data, "$.age") IS NOT NULL;

SELECT * FROM users
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(meta_data, "$.accepted_policy") = true;
```

**With mysql 5.7.9 +**

You can also just do this (shortcut for JSON_EXTRACT):

```sql
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE meta_data->"$.first_name" = 'bob'
```

You might notice your json data results are "quoted". You could use JSON_UNQUOTE, or you could use this, which is a shortcut of JSON_EXTRACT & JSON_UNQUOTE:

```sql
SELECT meta_data->>"$.first_name" FROM users
WHERE meta_data->>"$.first_name" IS NOT NULL
```

And to select data from within sub objects:

```sql
SELECT meta_data->>"$.address.tel" FROM users
WHERE meta_data->>"$.address.street" = "123 Main St"
```

docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html

Answer (score 6):

Use below query for WHERE operation with JSON Datatype Field in MySQL:

```sql
SELECT meta_data->'$.first_name' meta_data FROM users
WHERE INSTR(meta_data->'$.first_name', '123') > 0
```