# can't mysql generated int columns be nullable?

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

using Mysql with the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE participants (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    puuid CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    data JSON,
    project INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.project'))) STORED NULL,
    schoolCode VARCHAR(255) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.schoolCode'))) STORED,
    UNIQUE KEY (puuid)
);
```

when I try to run :

```
insert into participants(puuid,data) values('aasd','{"project":1}');
```

it work witout a problem
but when I try

```
insert into participants(puuid,data) values('aasd1','{"project":null}');
```

I get an error saying:

```
Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: 'null' for column 'project' at row 1
```

I double checked using

```
 show columns from participants;
```

which returns

[image: Results of show columns]

why won't it allow the JSON to have a null value to the project even though it states that the project column does allow nulls?

Is there no other solution than something like:

```
project INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (COALESCE(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.project')), 0)) STORED NULL,
```

UPDATE:
actually is seems that neither

```
 project INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (COALESCE(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.project')), 0)) STORED NULL,
```

nor

```
 project INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (IFNULL(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.project')), 0)) STORED NULL,
```

work.
I am about to give up on this GENERATED COLUMNS idea.

===================
UPDATE:

There seems to be two ways to go...

1. Ditching JSON in the DB as I ended up doing following the answer and comments provided by @Bill Karwin
2. If you still want to try using JSON in the DB, you should probably follow the answer provided by @aland (which if I would have received earlier I would have probably tried).

> "Two roads diverged in a yellow wood,  And sorry I could not travel
> both...."

(maybe next time)

Comment: Its a bug. Null is transformed into string "null" (4 chars, n,u,l,l) and that is not a number.(https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85755)

Comment: The bug was fixed in 8.0.21 - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-21.html#mysqld-8-0-21-json - released in 2020.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A missing JSON key extracts as an SQL `NULL`.

```
mysql> select json_extract('{"project":null}', '$.xyzzy') is null as is_it_null;
+------------+
| is_it_null |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
```

A JSON `null` value does not extract to an SQL `NULL`. It extracts as a JSON document which is the scalar value `'null'`.

```
mysql> select json_extract('{"project":null}', '$.project') is null as is_it_null;
+------------+
| is_it_null |
+------------+
|          0 |
+------------+
```

`JSON_UNQUOTE()` does not turn the JSON value `'null'` into an SQL `NULL`. It turns it it into the SQL string value `'null'`.

```
mysql> select json_unquote(json_extract('{"project":null}', '$.project')) is null as is_it_null;
+------------+
| is_it_null |
+------------+
|          0 |
+------------+
```

So your generated column is trying to parse a string value `'null'` to cast it as an integer, which fails in strict mode (the default):

```
mysql> select cast('null' as signed) as bad_integer;
+-------------+
| bad_integer |
+-------------+
|           0 |
+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'null'
```

You could fix it by comparing that string value to `'null'` and substituting SQL NULL this way:

```
mysql> select nullif(json_unquote(json_extract('{"project":null}', '$.project')), 'null') is null as is_it_null;
+------------+
| is_it_null |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
```

But this cannot be distinguished from the JSON string value `'null'`:

```
mysql> select nullif(json_unquote(json_extract('{"project":"null"}', '$.project')), 'null') is null as is_it_null;
+------------+
| is_it_null |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
```

Basically, JSON is a hot mess when combined with SQL. There are so many edge cases that behave in counter-intuitive ways that I have to say it is the worst feature to be added to SQL in many years.

Comment: Fyi https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85755

Comment: would basic storage and retrieval work? or should I expect additional issues around this choise to use JSON to store stuff in the DB?

Comment: You should expect other cases where JSON makes you spend a lot more time trying to figure out your storage and retrieval. Also be aware that storing data in JSON format takes about 2-3 times more storage space than storing the same data in normal rows and columns, so figure that into your storage cost estimation.

Comment: If it's not clear, I recommend to avoid using JSON in a relational database in almost all cases. At first it seems like a convenience, but it quickly results in more work and more cost.

Comment: If i don't need to look into the JSON I guess I could store it as just TEXT.
It has many fields And I realy don't want to have to add and remove columns from my table if a field is added or removed. not to mention the lengths of those queries...

Comment: The solution to ALTER TABLE inconvenience is not "never do an ALTER TABLE." It's better to embrace change, but use an [online schema change tool](https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-online-schema-change.html).

Comment: FWIW, `TEXT` can store JSON data, but it will use approximately the same space as the `JSON` data type (2-3 times more than using normal columns). But `TEXT` won't ensure that the JSON is properly formed.

Comment: thanks. I decided to take you suggestion and let others fight with the JSON inside MYSQL option. I will just deal with the changes if and when they arrive...

Answer (score 1):

After reading the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78097541/724039) from Bill,

You could/should do:

```
CREATE TABLE participants (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    puuid CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    data JSON,
    project INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE WHEN JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.project')) = 'null' 
                                          then null 
                                          else JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.project')) end) STORED NULL,
    schoolCode VARCHAR(255) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.schoolCode'))) STORED,
    UNIQUE KEY (puuid)
);
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/3s0iGeQ0)

Comment: although this probably works I don't like having to deal with nulls that are string and all this... following @Bill Karwin's suggestion and after reading the bug description I decided to let go of the JSON option. 
I will give you an up-vote as this is probably a solution that might help others that might choose to keep fighting with those json documents with mysql.

Answer (score 1):

If you used [JSON_VALUE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-value) (since 8.0.21), that would work as you expect

```
CREATE TABLE participants (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    puuid CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    data JSON,
    project INT AS (JSON_VALUE(data, '$.project')),
    schoolCode VARCHAR(255) AS (JSON_VALUE(data, '$.schoolCode')),
    UNIQUE KEY (puuid)
);
```

This then works `insert into participants(puuid,data) values('aasd1','{"project":null}');` and gives expected result.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75743288/131391

Comment: Are you missing the GENERATED ? and you point is that JSON_VALUE would return the expected null value where JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT returns the wrong type of null (as explained by @Bill Karwin ) ?

Comment: Using `GENERATED` is not required - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html and yes, exactly my point is that JSON_VALUE returns correct null values

Comment: thanks, I gave you an up voate. but since I did choose to accept and follow Bills answer I will leave it as the answer that solved my issue. I hope and believe you get many up votes. I will add some update to my Q to clarify that your solution should be considered for those choosing to use JSON.