# MySQL JSON query ERROR "Missing a closing quotation mark in string"

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-json

Edit:

Just realized I left out the closing quote here:
`{"area": "jp", "type": "female, "tag": {"411": "Doo Wop"}}`, I mistyped it in the original question but this quote is actually included in db column, I apologize for misunderstanding caused by this mistake, it has been fixed now.

---

I came across this problem a couple of hours ago, no luck in hours of Google searching.

I'm using MySQL 8.0

There is one column in a table whose data is stored as TEXT in json format:

```
mysql> select author_class from author limit 1 offset 36273;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| author_class                                                           |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"area": "jp", "type": "female", "tag": {"411": "Doo Wop"}}             |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

There are other rows whose `"tag"` field is empty like below:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| author_class                                                           |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"area": "ru", "type": "male", "tag": ""}                               |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What I want to do is to select rows whose `"tag"` field is not empty, like the first example.

I have tried something like this, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49053342/11887333), but the following error occured:

```
mysql> SELECT author_id, author_class ->> "$.tag" FROM author WHERE author_class ->> "$.tag" IS NOT NULL;
ERROR 3141 (22032): Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_extract: "Missing a closing quotation mark in string." at position 325.
```

and this didn't work either:

```
mysql> SELECT author_id, author_class ->> "$.tag" FROM xiami_author WHERE author_class -> "$.tag" IS NOT NULL;
ERROR 3141 (22032): Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_extract: "Missing a closing quotation mark in string." at position 325.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your `"type"` field in both examples is missing its value's closing quote: `"type": "male,`. Those need to be fixed or this is not valid JSON and cannot be used.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I wonder how they got those invalid values into the table in the first place.

Comment: It may be stored in a TEXT column. If it were a JSON column, it would not allow an invalid JSON document to be inserted.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski  Just realized I left out the closing quote in the original question but this quote is actually included in database column, I mistyped it, really sorry for misunderstanding caused by this mistake, it has been fixed now.

Comment: But "Missing a closing quotation" is exactly the error message you would get with a similar error in your data. Examine your full JSON and look for those.